Highlighted web part - KQL - hide current page from the results
I have the use case where I would like to use the Highlighted content web part on each news page where I display and filter another related news. It works well but unfortunately within the results there is also the news page where it is used. Do you know if there some tokens (e.g. Page.ID) or parametrs I can use that I will filter out the current news from the list. It works well for Modern Search web part so I supposed it can work same way.
Code:
Path:https://manicalab.sharepoint.com/sites/MMraveniste/SitePages/ PromotedState:2 FirstPublishedDate>={Today-1} -ListItemId:{Page.ID}
HCWP settings

Modern Search web part settings

